# Which is the best time of year to visit Bali?

Tags: weather-and-climate, indonesia, bali

I am planning to visit Bali and I want to do so before the end of 2015. I am looking for best time to visit Bali. I like to enjoy a little bit of rain (not too much) a pleasant weather and I am not into surfing or any other water sports. The purpose is mainly site seeing and photography and I dont want to travel in harsh summer. Please suggest the best time of the year to visit BALI.

> Important Thing is that I don't like the place to be dry, I like
>   greenery all around when I visit. :)

Comment: Have you tried looking at some standard temperature and rainfall charts for Bali?

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes I checked out but it is confusing when checked with the peak season.

Answer (score 9):

It is a tropical area, other than the density of the rain there is no much difference in the weather, temperatures are from 28-30C around the year.

**Dry season**: April – September. With May, June and July being the coolest months when temperatures 'drop' to 28C.

**Monsoon season**: starts in October and ends in March.

Source: [indonesiatravelplan.co.uk](http://www.indonesiatravelplan.co.uk/when-to-travel-to-indonesia.htm)

Comment: +1. Note that it rains regularly even in the "dry" reason, so Bali is tropical and lush all year round.

Comment: Rain in Jakarta means seven-hour traffic jams, rain in Bali means another cocktail at the resort bar ;)

Comment: @jpatokal EXACTLY :) :)

Comment: @MeNoTalk: Will there be water in the waterfalls in bali during June & July?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of **weather**, the best time to visit Bali would be **April–June and September** when it's a **dry season** and not as crowded as July-August. **Experience**-wise, the best time to visit Bali is **June through November**. 
[image: Best time to visit Bali based on seasonal experiences]

If you are interested in cultural events, I would recommend **March** as it's the month when the **Balinese New Year (Nyepi)** and **Omed-Omedan Festival** are celebrated. Hope everyone has a great time in Bali!

Answer (score 1):

Bali seems to be a major destination for Australian visitors during their holiday season. One reason for this is because from some places in Australia it is both less expensive and less time consuming to travel to Indonesia than all the way across Australia.
Thus many australian families choose to meet in Bali once a year instead visiting each other in Australia.

That's why you might want to avoid this time of the year because it might be less busy in hotels and at sightseeing spots.

Here is an online source of Australian school holidays:
https://www.australia.com/en/facts-and-planning/useful-tips/australian-school-holidays.html